# Run automatically a Task Queue with java Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks, task, task-queue

I would like to let, the Task in the GAE Task Queue, start. I followed step by step the configuration from [Task Queue Java on GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/), but when i click (for example) a link on my web-site (that call the Servlet which start the Task), it only put the Task in the Queue (as i can see on 'Task Queues link' on my AppEngine Console) and it never starts. It successfully starts only if i click the right-side button 'Run Now' (below 'Actions' column).

So, does anyone know how to let it start automatically (without go to the AppEngine Console and click every time on 'Run Now')?

Thank you so much

[Edit] Adding code:

[HTML Web page]:

```
<a href="/tasks/callTaskServlet">Call Task Servlet</a>
```

[CallTaskServlet.java]:

```
public class CallTaskServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
        queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/tasks/taskServlet").param("act", "refresh").retryOptions(RetryOptions.Builder.withTaskRetryLimit(1)));

    }

}
```

[TaskServlet.java]:

```
public class TaskServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = req.getParameter("act");
        LOGGER.warning(action);

        //Doing my stuff here…
    }

}
```

[web.xml]:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Task</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.TaskServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Task</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tasks/taskServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CallTask</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.CallTaskServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CallTask</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tasks/callTaskServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[Task Queues AppEngine]:
[Task Queues AppEngine](http://i59.tinypic.com/1058lqo.jpg)

[Log GAE (/tasks/taskServlet not run)]
[Log GAE](http://i59.tinypic.com/f3rs6v.png)

Did i miss something? I hope it's sufficient.

Comment: Show how you create a task and add it to the queue.

Comment: In the same way is mentioned by Google. Anyway, give me a minute to paste it and edit my question.

Comment: Ok, i edited it ;-) Please, have a look now. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queue is paused. Click on "Resume queue" and it will work as it should.

Note that the queue will never resume by itself.

Comment: Ahahah! That was a stupid oversight. Thank you Andrei! Thank you so much :-)